# Xerox printer or any network printer through router NAT

Tags: networking, router, printer, nat

Is possible set port 9100 forwarding of a Xerox or any other network printer for use it outside of the LAN?

I configured 9100 TCP/UDP forward to "Printer IP": 9100 on the local router. But testing it from a remote pc with `nmap` say is not open/listen.

Printer makers disable this possibility cause security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but if you are asking the question you should not.

Port 9100 is a standard tcp connection so it will work like any other. Assign your printer a static IP, make sure it has a default gateway and map the port to your router. **Then expect miscreants to scan your IPs and print to it wasting your consumables**  (When you want to print to it remotely you need to use your routers external IO to connect).

While I have used this technology with other printers I've not used Xerox. It is possible, but unlikely Xerox are firewalling the printer. If thats the case, you should be able to remove this restriction.

A better way to use this printer remotely would be to set up a VPN on your router and connect to that, then print acriss it (rather thrn exposing port 9100 remotely)